# Not able to deselect all checlboxes, after delete

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have 3 checkboxes and a master checkbox to select or deselect them all.

The master checkbox works fine until I delete some rows from my table. When some data has been deleted, I can check the master checkbox to select them all again but I am not able to deselect them. This is how it looks like:

[image]

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="serviceTable" #matTableService class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th style="width: 200px" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()" (change)="toggleAllServices()" [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"></mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)" (change)="selection.toggle(row)"> </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

```js
selection = new SelectionModel<Services>(true, []);

toggleAllServices(): void {
  console.log(this.selection.selected, 'selected')
  console.log(this.serviceTable, 'services');
  if (this.isAllSelected()) {
    this.selection.clear();
    this.allServicesAreSelected = false;
    return;
  }
  this.selection.select(... this.serviceTable);
  this.allServicesAreSelected = true;
}

isAllSelected(): boolean {
  return this.selection.selected.length === this.serviceTable.length
}
```

This is how I delete:

```js
deleteMultipleServices():void {
  const SELECTED_IDS:Array<number> = [];
  for (let item of this.selection.selected) {
    SELECTED_IDS.push(item.id);
  }
  this.serviceTable = this.serviceTable.filter((serviceValue, i) => !SELECTED_IDS.includes(i))
  this.matTableService.renderRows();
}
```

My problem is, as soon as I have deleted a row, I never get into the if-statement `if (this.isAllSelected()) {`, since `this.serviceTable` returns 2 objects, which is correct but `this.selection.selected` returns 3 objects, which is wrong since I have deleted one. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: attach your complete service.ts and component.ts file...it will be helpful to figure out the problem.

Comment: Are there console errors? It looks like there must be.

Comment: I am pretty sure deletion logic is wrong. you should also remove the item from selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have deleted items, you should clear the selection.

This should do the magic:

```js
this.selection.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it once -

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th style="width: 200px" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()" (change)="$event ? toggleAllServices() : null" 
      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"></mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row): null"> </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help.

Comment: In your deleteMultipleServices() method, you should clear the selection -

this.selection.clear();